# Does the C99 standard guaranteed the binary representation of unsigned int?

Tags: c, portability, c99, standards-compliance

### C99 (ISO/IEC 9899:1999)

> #### 6.2.6.2/1 Integer types
>
> The values of any padding bits are unspeciﬁed.<sup>45)</sup> A valid
> (non-trap) object representation of a signed integer type where the
> sign bit is zero is a valid object representation of the corresponding
> unsigned type, and shall represent the same value.
>
> **For any integer
> type, the object representation where all the bits are zero shall be a
> representation of the value zero in that type.**

In the C99 standard, an integer type where all the bits are zero is guaranteed to represent the value `0` in that respective type. However, does this guarantee that the underlying binary value is what we expect it to be?

For example:

```
unsigned x = 42;
```

We'd normally expect a machine to store this decimal `42` value in memory as the binary `101010` value.

However, could some eccentric machine architecture store the same decimal `42` value as the binary `011011` value (not necessarily for a practical reason but simply because it can)?

If so, consider the following code utilizing a right shift operation:

```
unsigned y = x>>1;    /* 101010>>1 or 011011>>1 */
```

Would `y` hold the decimal value `21` (`10101` in binary), or the decimal value `13` (`01101` in binary)?

Does the C99 standard make any guarantee about the decimal representation of an unsigned integer type after a bitwise operation -- e.g. is a right shift guaranteed to be equivalent to an integer division by `2` on all machine architectures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The representation of the integer isn't specified in the standard.
However, the behavior of `>>` and `<<` is defined according to the meaning of bits, not their position.
So `>> 1` moves the bit representing 4 to the bit representing 2, regardless of where these bits actually are.

Quoting the [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) section 6.5.7:

> The result of **E1 >> E2** is **E1** right-shifted **E2** bit positions. If **E1** has an unsigned type
>   or if **E1** has a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of **E1 / 2<sup>E2</sup>**. If **E1** has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-deﬁned.

Answer (score 1):

The `>>` operator will move bits around. Under a normal system, that means just shifting them. But in reality, we're taking the bit that represents position `2^3`, and moving it to position `2^2`, no matter where it is.

So on all systems, `assert(42 >> 1 == 21)`.

---

As to your second question, **yes**, as long as you ignore trap / padding bits. Those can obviously be different, but are also generally invisible to you.

Comment: Can you post a reference to somewhere where this information can be verified?

Comment: @sharth Do you mean `42 >> 1 == 21`?

Comment: @VilhelmGray: I did mean that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The standard does not guarantee anything about how things are physically stored in memory. There's no need for that. The machine can be ternary, decimal or analog at physical level, not binary. The machine is not even required to have physical bits.

All it guarantees about unsigned int is that the bitwise operators affect "bits" as elements of binary positional representation of the number. These are actually *virtual* bits. They can directly correspond to physical bits (as is typically the case in practice) or they can be purely conceptual.

The `>>` operator is guaranteed to shift those virtual bits to the right, meaning that it is always guaranteed to divide a positive integral value by 2. So, for the initial value of `x = 42` this `x = x >> 1` is guaranteed to produce `21` in `x`. That means that if some machine physically represented `42` as `011011`, the compiler for that machine would be required to generate code that would change that representation of `42` to the representation of `21` (whatever it is), even if physically the latter did not look like "right shifted" `011011` pattern.

Comment: The standard requires that if `sizeof(someType)` is `n`, a value of type `someType` may be decomposed into `n` values in the range 0..`UCHAR_MAX`, and further requires that `UCHAR_MAX+1` be a power of two.  While one could theoretically use a machine with ten-state storage tubes to run C, one would have to do something having each group of five store a value from 00000 to 65535 to represent a `char` or `short`, and never have any group of five registers hold a value of 65536 or higher.  Not exactly efficient.