# Can someone tell me why this program prints -56?

Tags: c, casting, ascii

This code prints `-56` and I'm not sure why

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("%d\n", ((int)(char)200));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because `char` implicitly is `signed char` on your platform.

Do

```
printf("%d\n", ((int)(unsigned char)200));
```

to get

```
200
```

Comment: Or better yet, `printf("%d\n", 200);`.

Comment: Or I suppose, if you are in a really crazy mood, `printf("200");`.

Answer (score 3):

- The type `char` is inconsistent towards the rest of the C language, since `char` can be either signed or unsigned. The C standard states it as implementation-defined behavior, meaning that the compiler can implement it in either way. Your particular compiler seems to implement `char` as equal to `signed char`.
- Because of the above, `char` should never be used for anything else but strings. It is bad practice to use for arithmetic operations. Such code relies on impl.defined behavior.
- The type `int` is always equal to  `signed int`. This is required by the C standard.
- Thus on your specific system, the code you have written is equal to: `(signed int)(signed char)200`.
- When you attempt to store the value 200 in a variable equivalent to `signed char`, it will overflow and get interpreted as -56 (on a two's complement system).
- When you cast a `signed char` containing -56 to a `signed int`, you get -56.

Answer (score 1):

The number 200 is out of the value range for `signed char`. It wraps around into the negative value range in a two's complement way.

Obviously the (implicit) signedness of `char` is defined to be `signed` on your platform. Note that this is not mandated by the standard. If it were `unsigned`, your program would print 200. For further reading on this topic:

- [Can someone explain how the signedness of char is platform specific?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1211982/1025391)

Obviously, the size of the `char` type is 8 bits on your platform. The definition of this quantity is unspecified by the language specification as well. If it were larger, the program may very well print 200, just as you expected. For further reading on this topic:

- [Is char guaranteed to be exactly 8-bit long?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/881894/1025391)

Also note, that it is not specified by the standard that integer types must use the two's complement binary representation. On a different platform, the cast may even produce a completely different result. For further reading:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Comparison_table

Comment: But the OP is using `char`, not `signed char`. The signedness of `char` is implementation-defined, so this answer isn't complete.

Comment: I do not think that http://stackoverflow.com/q/17045231/1025391 should be quoted for the explanation “the cast may even produce a completely different result”. The linked question is about representations. The semantics of the cast to `T1` of a value of type `T2` do not have to have anything to do with the representation of either `T1` or `T2`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq I found a better reference now, I think.

Answer (score 1):

`char` is `signed`, and `int` is `signed` (by default on your platform).

`(signed char)11001000` = -56 decimal

`(signed int)0000000011001000` = 200 decimal

Have a look at [Signed number representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations)

Comment: Not at all. char is signed, so when the compiler casts to an int, it perform sign extension, so 11001000 is converted to 11111111111111111111111111001000 (for a 32-bit int)

Comment: This is still incorrect. `char` is signed on his platform and so is `int`.

Comment: Also, the hex codes are complete nonsense. Are you trying to write BCD or something? Or "BCH" I suppose.. binary-coded hexadecimal?

Answer (score 0):

char is 8bits signed  from -128~127  so 200 is out of the value range